# Android make Call from specific 3rd party Voip App (like Cisco Jabber) using Telephony Manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, cisco, telephonymanager

I am making a call from my Android Application and it lists a set of apps that is capable of placing calls and user can select one to place calls. But what I want to know, Is there a way to redirect the call to a **specific 3rd party VOIP App (like Cisco Jabber)** instead of listing all apps** capable of placing calls. I have tried using

register for `ACTION_NEW_OUT_GOING_CALLS` using a broadcast receiver to interrupt the outgoing calls but I dont know how to redirect the call following is the code of broadcast receiver.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    Log.d("Test", ""+phoneNumber);

    TelephonyManager telephoneManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try {
        Class<?> c = telephoneManager.getClass();
        Class className = Class.forName(c.getName());
        Log.d("Test", c.getSimpleName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<ResolveInfo> callAppList =  context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    Log.d("Test", ""+callAppList.size());
    if(callAppList.size() > 0)
        Log.d("Test", callAppList.get(0).activityInfo.targetActivity);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of solutions.

1. Does the 3rd party provide APIs ? You could integrate with that (like the skype API)
2. If the 3rd party software has an activity that can accept your call, then you can forward the control to that activity by providing an appropriate intent.

I'm not aware that the telephony manager can capture data about VOIP calls. I believe its responsibility is specific to calls on the phone itself. I've not worked with the telephony manager before, so I would not know.

Comment: No the 3rd party App is not providing any APIs to interact with!

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Each party will use a protocol and API of their own to make calls. The packets could be in UDP / TCP and the wire format itself varies greatly between providers. There cannot be any common interface that can link them all together without applying the right glue to each provider.

EDIT - 

I think jitsi comes closest to what you are trying to do. They are making an android port of their app, but it has some way to go. You could in theory ask jitsi to handle calls for you if the app existed on android. https://jitsi.org/index.php/Documentation/FAQ#android

Comment: No we can do it, In Cisco Jabber app they have an option to make the call go via Ciso jabber instead of native dialler if they can do it so can we :) we only need to find the way to do it my friend